# How to save what i print as image

Tags: vb.net, printing

i hope someone can help me with this problem.

so, i have a code that will print records in the data grid view and i hope to save that as image how do i make that happen, i search through the web but i dont see one that solve this problem. i even see one from stackoverflow but the approach is different.

this is the code:

```
        Dim addressFont As New Font(dgvWarehouse.Font.FontFamily, 10, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
        Dim logoImage As Image = CType(My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("logo1"), Image)
        e.Graphics.DrawImage(logoImage, CInt((e.PageBounds.Width - 800) / 2), 10, 300, 180)
        Dim companyname As String = "Sample"
        Dim address As String = "Sample"
        Dim number As String = "Sample"
        Dim email As String = "Sample"
        e.Graphics.DrawString(companyname, CompanyFont, Brushes.Black, CSng(e.PageBounds.Width - 1100 / 2), 60)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(address, addressFont, Brushes.Black, CSng(e.PageBounds.Width - 1100 / 2), 90)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(number, addressFont, Brushes.Black, CSng(e.PageBounds.Width - 1100 / 2), 105)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(email, addressFont, Brushes.Black, CSng(e.PageBounds.Width - 1100 / 2), 120)
        ''

        Dim headerFont As New Font(dgvWarehouse.Font.FontFamily, 15, FontStyle.Italic, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
        Dim actualWidth As Integer = dgvWarehouse.Columns.Cast(Of DataGridViewColumn).Sum(Function(c) c.Width)
        Dim percentage As Decimal = CDec(((100 / actualWidth) * e.MarginBounds.Width) / 100)
        Dim header As String = "Warehouse Inventory"
        Dim footer As String
        Dim startX As Integer = e.MarginBounds.Left - 30
        Dim startY As Integer = e.MarginBounds.Top
        Dim r As Rectangle


        Dim szf As SizeF = e.Graphics.MeasureString(header, headerFont)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(header, headerFont, Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds.Left + (e.MarginBounds.Width - szf.Width) / 2, startY - (r.Height - 80))
        footer = "Page " & pageCounter.ToString
        szf = e.Graphics.MeasureString(footer, headerFont)
        e.Graphics.DrawString(footer, headerFont, Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds.Left + (e.MarginBounds.Width - szf.Width) / 2, e.MarginBounds.Bottom + 5)

        startY += 100

        ''this is the text alignment
        Dim sf As New StringFormat
        sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center
        sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center

        Dim gridFont As New Font(dgvWarehouse.Font.FontFamily, dgvWarehouse.Font.Size, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)

        '' this create the table header column
        'If startRow = 0 Then
        For x As Integer = 0 To dgvWarehouse.Columns.Count - 1
            r.X = startX
            r.Y = startY
            r.Width = CInt((dgvWarehouse.Columns(x).Width + 15) * percentage)
            r.Height = dgvWarehouse.Rows(0).Height
            dgvWarehouse.Columns(x).HeaderCell.Style.BackColor = Color.Gray
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(dgvWarehouse.Columns(x).HeaderCell.Style.BackColor), r)
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, r)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(dgvWarehouse.Columns(x).HeaderText, gridFont, Brushes.White, r, sf)
            startX += r.Width
        Next

        startY += r.Height
        'End If

        '' this create the table header row
        For y As Integer = startRow To dgvWarehouse.Rows.Count - 1
            If y = dgvWarehouse.NewRowIndex Then Continue For
            startX = e.MarginBounds.Left
            For x As Integer = 0 To dgvWarehouse.Columns.Count - 1
                r.X = startX - 30
                r.Y = startY
                r.Width = CInt((dgvWarehouse.Columns(x).Width + 15) * percentage)
                r.Height = dgvWarehouse.Rows(0).Height
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, r)
                e.Graphics.DrawString(If(Not dgvWarehouse.Rows(y).Cells(x).Value Is Nothing, dgvWarehouse.Rows(y).Cells(x).Value.ToString, ""),
                                        gridFont, Brushes.Black, r, sf)

                startX += r.Width
            Next
            startY += r.Height
            If startY >= e.MarginBounds.Bottom - 10 Then
                If y < dgvWarehouse.Rows.Count - 1 Then
                    e.HasMorePages = True
                    pageCounter += 1
                    startRow = y + 1
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next
```

i can just save the datagridview as image but that is not what i want. i want to save the one in print preview where there is an icon and has stylish table.

Answer (score 0):

Move your code to its own method and replace all instances of `e.Graphics` with a parameter of type `Graphics`. You can then call that method anywhere and pass it a `Graphics` object created any way you like. For instance, if you had this code:

```vb
Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(...) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
    e.Graphics.DrawString(...)
End Sub
```

you could change it to this:

```vb
Private Sub DrawPage(g As Graphics)
    g.DrawString(...)
End Sub

Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(...) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage
    DrawPage(e.Graphics)
End Sub
```

to get the same result. You can then do this elsewhere:

```vb
Dim img As New Bitmap(...)
Dim g = Graphics.FromImage(img)

DrawPage(g)
```

to do the same drawing on your `Bitmap` as you printed. As your printing is fairly complex, there may be some other small adjustments that you need to make but the principle remains.